# Spring Boot with Embedded Tomcat behind AWS ELB - HTTPS redirect

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, spring-security, spring-boot, amazon-elb

Running Spring boot application port 8080 on EC2 instance.

AWS ELB configured to redirect

```
     80 -> 8080
     443 (SSL termination happens here) -> 8080
```

Application uses Spring Security and if you user arrives to http://example.com it will redirect to . I would like to login page to use SSL.

Spring security snippet:

```
 http.requiresChannel().antMatchers("/login", "/logout").requiresSecure();
```

We are running into redirect loop which makes sense.

To Spring Boot application it looks like all requests are made to non-secured port 8080, it redirects to https://example.com, goes through ELB and again gets request on 8080

Any ideas on how to run this with AWS ELB ???

Answer (score 3):

Looks like this did the trick:

```
@Component
public class TomcatCustomizer implements EmbeddedServletContainerCustomizer {

@Override
public void customize(ConfigurableEmbeddedServletContainer container) {
    TomcatEmbeddedServletContainerFactory tomcat = (TomcatEmbeddedServletContainerFactory) container;
    tomcat.addConnectorCustomizers(new TomcatConnectorCustomizer() {
        @Override
        public void customize(Connector connector) {
            connector.setSecure(true);  
        }
    });

}
```

}

Answer (score 2):

You will have to [instantiate your own `EmbeddedServletContainerFactory`](http://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/howto-embedded-servlet-containers.html#howto-enable-multiple-connectors-in-tomcat) and set the `secure` property on the connector for this container to `true`.  After that your Ant matcher rule will work.

Alternatively, you can check out the [Spring Boot source code](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot) available on Github, add code for reading a boolean configuration property called `server.channel.secure`, setting it on the embedded Tomcat connector and submit a pull request for the Spring team to incorporate into the next release.

Comment: Thank you for pointing out secure property .. looks like there is fairly easy way to set it. I posted answer above.